# Echo Post ID from Post Slug or Post Title

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to get a post ID based on the post tile or slug (doesn't matter to me which one). After that I want to add the ID to a shortcode.

**Working code**

```
<?php 
    $test123 = get_post(30);
    echo $test123->ID; /* this works and returns 30 */
?>

<?php 
echo do_shortcode("[shortcode id='{$test123->ID}']"); /* this also works */
?>
```

So the next step is get the post ID based on slug or title. How do I do this? I tested different codes but nothing works till so far.

Many thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To get post by slug use `url to postid()` function ([documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid)):

```
$post_id = url_to_postid( $url );
```

To get post by title you can use `get_page_by_title()` function ([documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title)):

```
$post = get_page_by_title( 'Your post title', OBJECT, 'post' );
$post_id = $post->ID;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Can you give me an example of how this code works? I try this:

`$post = url_to_postid( $url, 'test123' );
echo $post->ID;`

Comment: the code needs to connect to another post and fetch the id based on the title or slug

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution

```
<?php 

 $homepage1 = url_to_postid('/here-is-my-custom-post-permalink/post-slug/');
 echo do_shortcode("[my_shortcode id='{$homepage1}']"); 

?>
```

If it is a normal post, you can skip the /here-is-my-custom-post-permalink/ part